# Spatial and temporal derivatives of a perturbation

Tags: perturbation-theory

Suppose we have a function of the form $A=A(\vec{x},t)$ that depends on space and time. I want to know why, if $A(\vec{x},t)$ is considered to be a perturbation, then both $\partial A/\partial t$ and $\vec{\nabla}A$ are also perturbations. My reasoning for the time derivative is the following. If we work in Fourier space, then we can write:

$$A(\vec{x},t)=\sum_{\vec{k}}A_{\vec{k}}\cdot e^{-i(\omega t+\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}=i\omega A(\vec{x},t)$$

which is proportional to the original perturbation, and is therefore also a perturbation. However, this reasoning does not seem to be valid for the case of the spatial derivatives, since:

$$\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{\vec{k}}-ik_iA_\vec{k}\cdot e^{-i(\omega t+\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}$$

Then, how can I proceed to prove that $\vec{\nabla}A$ is a perturbation?

Comment: From your description it seems you only require those quantities to be of the same order as the original $A$ to prove they are 'perturbations', though I doubt the usage of this term is correct in this case. Having said that, you literally just proved it yourself because $-ik_i$ is indeed a scalar factor in front of $A$. The reasoning applies to the spatial derivatives just as well as to the time derivatives. There is not really a difference between the two derivatives btw.

Comment: @Rescy_ Honestly I'm not sure if what I am doing is correct. All I know is that the physics book that I'm studying assumes that the temporal and spatial derivatives of a perturbation are also perturbations, and I don't know why. So my reasoning could very well not be the correct reason. But anyway, in the case of the spatial derivatives, the scalar factor in front of each term of the Fourier series is different for each term, so it cannot be extracted outside of the sum. Doesn't this change the reasoning?

Comment: No it does not change the argument. You are free to think of each component of spatial derivative as a single entity, so that each component is no different from the time derivative - indeed if you claim time being the 0th component of derivaiton, as is usual in Relativity and QFT, you see there is no difference in reasoning the two scenarios you discussed in your question. Alternatively you may want to consider all spatial derivatives as a single vector $\nabla A$, in which case it is (given by ur calculation) $\nabla A=-i\vec{k}\cdot A$ which is indeed a perturbation.